# Getting list of all recipients in an email collector for a survey via SurveyMonkey API

Tags: python, api, email, automation, surveymonkey

I have a survey that went out to 100 recipients via the built-in email collector. I am trying to design a solution in python that will show only the list of recipients (email addresses) who have not responded (neither "Completed" nor "Partial"). Is there any way to get this list via the SurveyMonkey API?

One possible solution is to store the original list of 100 recipients in my local database, get the list of recipients who have already responded using the get_respondent_list api, and then do a matching to find the people who have not responded. But I would prefer to not approach it this way since it involves storing the original  list of recipients locally.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently not a way to do this via the SurveyMonkey API - it sounds like your solution is the best way to do things.

I think your best bet is to go with your solution and email api-support@surveymonkey.com and ask them about the feasibility of adding this functionality in future.  It sounds like what you need is a `get_collector_details` method that returns specific details from a collector, which doesn't currently exist.